# How to reset the background buttons (swipe menu) of the recyclerview programmatically?

Tags: java, filter, android-recyclerview, listadapter, itemtouchhelper

I have a recyclerview which has a swipe menu (background buttons) on my android app.
The article that I referred to is: https://codeburst.io/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28

This article was quite helpful and I succeeded to embed the basic function of swipe menu features.
However, after the filter function for the list of the recyclerview was embedded, I noticed that I have to figure out a way how to reset/clear the swipe menu manually/programmatically because after the list of the cardviews are filtered, the swipe menu is lingered in the background of each list but I have no clues how to solve this issue. (as shown in the attached pictures)

The things that I tried are:
  notifyDataSetChanged by Adapter - not work
  notifyItemChanged by Adapter - not work
  reset the ItemTouchHelper (put null and reattach) - not work
  recyclerview.performClick to reset the state of the ItemTouchHelper - not work

According to the article, it seems clicking a recyclerview resets the state of the ItemTouchHelper.
Could you please teach me how to click a recyclerview programmatically or any other solutions if available?

The following code is a fraction of the source from the article that I assumed relevant to solve this issue...

```
private void setTouchUpListener(final Canvas c, 
    final RecyclerView recyclerView, 
    final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, 
    final float dX, final float dY, 
    final int actionState, final boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                SwipeController.super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, 0F, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
                recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                setItemsClickable(recyclerView, true);
                swipeBack = false;
                buttonShowedState = ButtonsState.GONE;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[After the swipe menu emerged by swiping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MOjM.jpg)
[Swipe menus remained after filtering the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtJiF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that adding the layout-change listener on the recyclerview could remove the swipe menu.

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(@NotNull final RecyclerView recyclerView, @NotNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    myRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    myRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            clearSwipeMenu();
        }
    });
}
```

....

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(@NotNull Canvas c, @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NotNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                        float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    if (actionState == ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        if (buttonShowedState != ButtonsState.GONE) {
            if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.LEFT_VISIBLE) dX = Math.max(dX, buttonWidth);
            if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.RIGHT_VISIBLE) dX = Math.min(dX, -buttonWidth);
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        } else {
            setTouchListener(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }

    if (buttonShowedState == ButtonsState.GONE) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
    currentItemViewHolder = viewHolder;
}
```

....

```
public void clearSwipeMenu() {
    if(currentItemViewHolder!=null){
        clearView(myRecyclerView, currentItemViewHolder);
        currentItemViewHolder = null;
    }
}
```